# How to tell when past periods have been changed?

Tags: quickbooks-online

In Quick Books Online, suppose a period is closed but then someone goes back and edits it. Like maybe they add some new expense for something that was 6 months ago.

Is there a way I can see any sort of audit log of when changes like this are made? That is, I don't want to see a full report of anything for January, but I want to see anything that's changed for January in the last 30 days.

Is something like that possible?

For more context, I'm a software developer and it would be pretty significant overhead for me to pull all data for all our customers all the time. I need a way to see if data for past periods has changed. QuickBooks allows users to change posted periods, so I need a way to know if this has happened so I can refresh these periods on our end.

Comment: You're probably looking for https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/webhooks.

Comment: @ceejayoz While that looks promising, it doesn't appear to have a hook for Transactions which is what I think I would need. I did look at the TransactionList report and tried to see about filtering by start_createddate and end_created date but I'm not getting any results no matter what time range I put. Same result (which is no results) when filtering by start_moddate and end_moddate. I'm not even sure what those filters are for if the don't return results based on when transactions were created/modified?? Color me confused.

Comment: @ceejayoz Admittedly I'm a bit of a noob though, so please enlighten me if I'm off track!

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh, I just realized this is the question I posted in the money site and not the stackoverflow site. I did post another question regarding the api, but here I am looking for how to access this information manually through the web portal UI. I only added a statement about what I'm doing for context; but I'm not trying to ask a code question here. Just wanting to know how any end user could find this information.